# centering text in <p> with flex

Tags: html, css

Explain me please

```
p {display: flex; justify-content: center}
```

why `justify-content:center` doesn't work when there are too much (more then one) text lines in p?

Comment: How about some code? A JSFiddle demonstrating the issue would be great.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/64q7u/ updated

Comment: Not really sure what you're trying to accomplish by assigning this to `<p>` elements. `display:flex` is generally for flex containers. `justify-content` is for justifying children, not a replacement for `text-align`.

Comment: another one sorry http://jsfiddle.net/64q7u/3/

Comment: @agrm I believe that is the answer. Use `display:flex` for centering child elements. Use `text-align` for text.

Comment: maybe it's idiotic but I'm doing a site right now, with such line in css body * {display: flex;}

Comment: @user3827356 May I ask why? If you think about it, elements has different display values by default. Some are block level elements, others are inline. We've ended up on the different choices by years of experience, trial and error, tests of what's best for each element. I love the whole idea of flexbox, but only when applied to specific elements where it's needed. Also, browser support is not awesome, such as IE<10 and still required vendor prefixes. Not to ruin your night and burn your motivation, but I think you may be wasting time going in the wrong direction here :-)

Comment: @agrm it's ok i am just learning, i thought it would be nice to have a general model for all elements, or smth like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Text-align` and `justify-content` are not alternative properties for text alignment. They are different properties with different goals. Where `text-align` is for specifying the alignment of text and inline content within a *block box*, `justify-content` is for justifying flex items in a *flex box*.

I've put together **[an example](http://jsfiddle.net/6xZ8Z/)** to demonstrate how `justify-content` and `text-align` can play together.

To reference the specs:

> [**text-align**: left | right | center | justify | inherit](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/text.html#propdef-text-align)
>
> This property describes how inline-level content of a block container is aligned

And from the Flexible box model layout:

> [**display**: flex|inline-flex](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/#flex-containers);
>
> This value causes an element to generate a block-level flex *container* box.
>
> [**justify-content**: flex-start | flex-end | center | space-between | space-around](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/#justify-content-property)**
>
> The justify-content property aligns flex items along the main axis of the current line of the flex container

These are some recommended resources to read up on the flexible box model layout:

- **[W3C's Working Draft](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/#flex-containers)**
- **[Chris Coyier's Guide to Flexbox](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)**